# Linux Routing "L3 Switch on a stick", single interface

Tags: linux-networking

I am trying to set up a Debian VM to behave essentially like a L3 switch, but with a single physical interface for multiple VLANs.

I'd like for the VM to be act as the gateway for each VLAN, and send anything it doesn't know how to route to the main router, both for inter-VLAN and internet-bound traffic.

I have four interfaces:

- `ens18 - vid 1 - 10.0.0.254`
- `ens18.10 - vid 10 - 10.0.1.254`
- `ens18.20 - vid 20 - 10.0.2.254`
- `ens18.30 - vid 30 - 10.0.3.254`

The following is happening:

- Interfaces can ping devices within their same vlan segment
- Interfaces can ping the main router on its main address and vlan addresses
- Interfaces *cannot* ping anything beyond their vlan segment, including the internet

Is there anything special I need to do as far as routing goes? I can't add multiple default gateways, but I know I can add extra routing tables however I've had no such luck with this.

Comment: You seem to want the VM to be a LAN router, not a layer-3 switch, which is first a layer-2 switch. The hosts should use the LAN router as the default gateway, and the WAN router should not have interfaces in the VLANs. You need a link (either physical or virtual) between the WAN router and LAN router. You need to tell the WAN router how to reach the networks on the other side of the LAN router, either with static routes (does not scale but may be simpler for small sites) or through a dynamic routing protocol. You only confuse the situation if both routers are connected to all networks.

Comment: That makes sense. So would I perhaps achieve this with an `iptables` rule to masquerade the traffic?
Then the VM receives traffic from the LAN segments and acts as the router, and only has the one connection upstream to the WAN router?

I think the main reason I was looking to have the VM forward everything in the way I originally described, and leave the main router to handle inter-VLAN is so I can still have the main router do firewall rules etc.

Comment: No. You only NAT where you must. This is simply routing. Save the NAT for the private to public routing, but only route in your own network.

Comment: So I ended up setting up another VM in network 10.0.3.0/24 and configured the main router which currently handles dhcp to give a default gw of the interface in that subnet (`ens18.30 - 10.0.3.254`). 

I can ping the internet, and `tcpdump` seems to suggest a ping from this new VM goes into ens18.30, then out of ens18 to the main router.

But this seems to break any VLAN segregation, as it's coming out of the interface on VID1.

Setting up another VM in a different VLAN segment with a firewall rule blocking the two segments confirms this as they can still ping each other despite the rule.